# What term describes implying an unspoken question?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is not an ethical, moral, or legal question - I'm looking for the language terminology relating to the quoted text of this hypothetical situation (simplified from a real-world one):

Bob gives Alex a monthly allowance. Whenever Alex needs more money or wants something, he will suggest the need and source, without actually asking a question, for example: "Bob, I'm short on money and know you got paid today, so was hoping to get some money early."

A similar question mentions "declarative questions", however in this situation, Alex never sounds like he is asking a question; rather, Alex's statements sound more like instructions or orders in that compliance is expected, and non-compliance is treated as a violation of an agreement that doesn't exist. (I know this is dysfunctional - again, I'm only looking for terminology.)

Is this just "passive voice" or is there a more specific term relating to a person's chronic inability to (or choice not to) make requests / ask direct questions?

**Update:** It seems "implies", "prompts", or "hints" seem to be the closest terms for this. I'll leave it open for a bit longer.

Comment: "Leading question" is halfway there: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/leading-question

Comment: Describing it as "Brought up the topic" or "raised the issue" or 'raised the question' are terms that might be used to describe similar approaches.

Comment: First, this is **not** passive voice, with or without scare quotes. In the trade, this is called an Indirect Speech Act, where one kind of sentence is used to imply some other kind. There are a variety of indirect speech acts, which are studied and discussed in the part of linguistics called [Pragmatics](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2016/ling001/pragmatics.html).

Comment: This is perhaps, more a behavioral communications question than on grammatical terms in the English language. The English language grammarians of old and new did not seem to have seen it necessary to categorize such manner of communications. Simply because it is not a grammatical issue. It is a style of speech pertaining to the behavioural psychology of the speaker.

Comment: Your first question is intriguing. Your second question, introduced in the last paragraph, is a psychodiagnostic query, which is off-topic for EL&U.

Comment: This has a lot more to do with his psychology. It's not about "passive voice" in the English syntax sense at all. It's just that the person ***implies*** a question by *asking* in the form of, it sounds like, a statement, or some flavor of indirect question/statement. He may do this b/c it gives better results than asking directly. He may do it out of some shame or personality quirk. However, I don't know of a phobia or disorder which causes this other than a typical social awkwardness or shyness and introverted personality which might be driving this act.

Comment: Please never ’simplify’ a hypothetical from a real-world situation.

Yours might not be an unreasonable example but please recognize, no-one, ever, speaks like that.

That said, John Lawler’s Pragmatics and Kace36’s details say it all. 

Whether or not Alex is asking a question please note, his statements don’t sound like instructions or orders, nor does it sound as though compliance is expected, nor that non-compliance might be relevant 

How could *passive voice* come into this?

What does the example have to do with any person's inability to make requests or ask direct questions?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin to clarify, this is a simplification in that I changed the unit involved to money (a topic most people can easily relate to without detailed explanation of the situation) and changed the names because the actual situation is tense, hotly debated, and involves legal disputes. The sentence quoted is otherwise an exact quote of the individual: "I'm short on [units] and know you [received some] today, so was hoping to get some [of my allocation] early."

Comment: " so was hoping to get some money early" There is some discussion as to whether this is a question or not. A more clear example: "I wonder if you will give me some money". Grammatically, not a question. However, there is  difference to saying it normally (statement of your wonder), and using inflection _as if you were asking a question_ (which makes it a polite question, more than a statement). Since the way you say it changes its interpretation, you can argue that that functionally makes it a question. Similarly, "Can I go home?" asks for **permission**, rather than stating the **ability** to

Comment: @Flater I see what you're saying, but Alex intentionally avoids reference to Bob when wanting Bob to act. In fact, Alex could speak to a third party with Bob present and still expect Bob to act. "Kate, I am short on money, though Bob just got paid today. I hope I get some of my allotment early."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a straightforward case of Alex ***prompting***, or at least attempting to prompt Bob.

From the OED (Login required)

> [prompt](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/152489?rskey=ZmZLLq&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid), v. 2a. trans. To incite to action; to move or induce (a
>   person, etc.) to or to do something.

Bob may find this annoying or passive-aggressive, but that is perhaps about the manner of prompting rather than the core action.

Answer (score 1):

As a addtion to 'to prompt', consider 'to hint'

> something that you say or do that shows what you think or want,
>   usually in a way that is not direct
>   (Cambridge Dictionary).